# Passing a String as a constructor parameter and getting "illegal start of type"

Tags: java, constructor

I recently started learning about inheritance in java but I am having a little bit of a problem here, can I put an actual word as a String (instead of a variable) on the constructor of the subclass?

I tried putting it as public Profesori(String emri, int vitiLindjes, "Ligjerate", String thirrjaAkademike) but no luck

```
public class Mesimdhenesi {
    private String emri;
    private int vitiLindjes;
    private String angazhimi;

    public Mesimdhenesi(String emri, int vitiLindjes, String angazhimi) {

        this.emri = emri;
        this.vitiLindjes = vitiLindjes;
        this.angazhimi = angazhimi;
    }
}

public class Profesori extends Mesimdhenesi {
    private String thirrjaAkademike;


    public Profesori(String emri, int vitiLindjes, "Ligjerate", String thirrjaAkademike) {

        super(emri,vitiLindjes);

        this.thirrjaAkademike = thirrjaAkademike;

    }
}
```

getting this error:
Profesori.java:6: error: illegal start of type
        public Profesori(String emri, int vitiLindjes, "Ligjerate", String thirrjaAkademike) {

Comment: Why is there  "Ligjerate" in the Profesori constructor signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
public Profesori(String emri, int vitiLindjes, String thirrjaAkademike) {

    super(emri, vitiLindjes, "Ligjerate");

    this.thirrjaAkademike = thirrjaAkademike;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a string literal in the definition of a method or a constructor.
If you want to pass the string "`Ligjerate"` as a parameter of the `super()` constructor, your  `Profesori` constructor should be something like:

```
public Profesori(String emri, int vitiLindjes, String thirrjaAkademike) {

        super(emri,vitiLindjes, "Ligjerate");

        this.thirrjaAkademike = thirrjaAkademike;

    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I got a little confused. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The idea isn't that wrong, you just put it in on the wrong part of your code.
Change this

```
public class Profesori extends Mesimdhenesi {
    private String thirrjaAkademike;


    public Profesori(String emri, int vitiLindjes, "Ligjerate", String thirrjaAkademike) {

        super(emri,vitiLindjes);

        this.thirrjaAkademike = thirrjaAkademike;

    }
}
```

to this:

```
public class Profesori extends Mesimdhenesi {
    private String thirrjaAkademike;


    public Profesori(String emri, int vitiLindjes, String thirrjaAkademike) {

        super(emri,vitiLindjes, "Ligjerate");

        this.thirrjaAkademike = thirrjaAkademike;

    }
}
```

you pass the actual word to the super constructor.

there were 2 problems in your code:

1. your super constructor didnt have enough parameters (you need 3 but you only gave 2)
2. the actual word in constructor as parameter